# Java method overriding, subclass taking a super type of the parameter type

Tags: java, oop, overriding

In java, we can narrow the return type and the throws exception type (or even erase the throws clause) :

```
abstract class A
{
  abstract CharSequence getName() throws NameNotAvailableException;
}

class B extends A
{
  String getName()
  {
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

But, what about parameter types (if A takes a `T`, then why not B takes `? super T`) as in :

```
abstract class A
{
  abstract void setName(final String name);
}

class B extends A
{
  void setName(final CharSequence name)
  {

  }
}
```

Let's consider this piece of code which i think is completely logical to me :

```
void handleA(final A a)
{
  a.setName("foo");
}

handleA(new B());
```

So what i'm saying is that `B` is still valid in the context of code using `A`.

Comment: I guess it's restricted because of the complexities it will add with method resolution when there are also overloaded methods with similar signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Because `CharSequence` is not only a `String`, while a `String` is a `CharSequence`. In other words `CharSequence` can also be `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`.

That's why you can not change the parameter type of `setName(String)` to `CharSequence`.